# Group list by specific field

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq

I'd like to show a list of lessons, grouped by date. 
I've tried several things, but I think the code below is my best try.
Although it still doesn't work out.

```
Public Function showSchedule(ByVal driver As Integer, month As Integer) As List(Of tbl_lesson)
    Dim result = From lesson In dc.tbl_lesson
                 Order By lesson.fk_calendar
                 Join c In dc.tbl_calendars On c.pk_calendar Equals lesson.fk_calendar
                 Join ls In dc.tbl_lessonseries On ls.pk_tbl_lessonseries  Equals  lesson.fk_tbl_lessonseries 
                 Join ts In dc.tbl_timeslots On ts.pk_timeslot Equals lesson.fk_timeslot
                 Where ls.fk_employee = Convert.ToInt16(driver) And c.month = month
                 Group lesson By lesson.fk_calendar Into grp = Group
                 Select grp

    Return result
End Function
```

Thanks in advance for your help!
Jannick

Comment: So what exactly isn't working about your current attempt?  Is lession.fk_calendar supposed to be the date field you are looking to group with?

Comment: Hi Jace, indeed. I'm trying to group the records that I put in a gridview by lesson.fk_calendar (which contains a unique date). But when I fire the button ("show schedule") which fills the gridview with above function it doesn't show anything. If I put the group by in comment in above function the button does fire. So there is something wrong with the group by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you group by a value, you get back an `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` which is essentially a collection of collections (segregated by the key values), but your function is trying to return a flat list of `tbl_lesson` values.

If you are trying to get a *distinct* list by the key value then you can pluck the first value out of each group:

```
Return result.Select(g => g.First()).ToList();  // will return a list of tbl_lesson items
```

If you just want to *order* by the key value, then just take out the grouping:

```
Dim result = From lesson In dc.tbl_lesson
             Order By lesson.fk_calendar
             Join c In dc.tbl_calendars On c.pk_calendar Equals lesson.fk_calendar
             Join ls In dc.tbl_lessonseries On ls.pk_tbl_lessonseries  Equals  lesson.fk_tbl_lessonseries 
             Join ts In dc.tbl_timeslots On ts.pk_timeslot Equals lesson.fk_timeslot
             Where ls.fk_employee = Convert.ToInt16(driver) And c.month = month
             Select grp

Return result.ToList()
```

Comment: Thanks D Stanley! The .First worked out fine for me!